# Reshift Nan values column dataframe if match with list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, shift

I want to rearrange column name values that contains Nan.

Condition that i want is, if string in list match with column[1], it will only reshift column values that contain row under matched string, so its my dataframe before shifted.

```
[in] : df
[Out]:

   column1     column2    column3 
0  aba abab    800.0      900.0
1  aaa acc     900.0      60.0 
2  bba jka     809.0      400.0
3  fff yy      521.0      490.0  
4  hkm asa j   290.0      321.0    
5  daa rr oo   88.0       Nan
6  jtuy ww ddw Nan        600.0
8  bkam ftf    Nan        Nan   
9  fgqefc      Nan        Nan
10 daas we fg  Nan        Nan   
11 judv mm mk  Nan        Nan   
12 hus gg hhh  Nan        Nan
```

and here my list

```
my_list= ['bba jka', 'hkm asa j']
```

so it my dataframe that i wanted, which name is df1

```
column1     column2    column3 
0  aba abab    800.0      900.0
1  aaa acc     900.0      60.0 
2  bba jka     Nan        Nan
3  fff yy      809.0      400.0  
4  hkm asa j   Nan        Nan    
5  daa rr oo   521.0      490.0
6  jtuy ww ddw 290.0      321.0
8  bkam ftf    88.0       Nan   
9  fgqefc      Nan        600.0
10 daas we fg  Nan        Nan   
11 judv mm mk  Nan        Nan   
12 hus gg hhh  Nan        Nan
```

I dont understand how to achieve df1 with shift and match, anyone can solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a suggestion, which might not be optimal:

**Step 1**: Preparations for `apply`:

```
match = df['column1'].str.fullmatch('|'.join(entry for entry in my_list))
df['shift'] = match.cumsum()
df['index'] = df.index
df.set_index('column1', drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Result (`df`) looks like:

```
            column2 column3  shift  index
column1                                  
aba abab      800.0   900.0      0      0
aaa acc       900.0    60.0      0      1
bba jka       809.0   400.0      1      2
fff yy        521.0   490.0      1      3
hkm asa j     290.0   321.0      2      4
daa rr oo      88.0     NaN      2      5
...
```

**Step 2**: "Shifting" via `apply` and `NaN` assingment via mask `match`:

```
df = df.apply(lambda row: df.shift(int(row.at['shift'])).iloc[int(row.at['index'])],
              axis='columns')
df[list(match)] = np.nan
```

**Step 3**: Clean up:

```
df.drop(['shift', 'index'], axis='columns', inplace=True)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

The result is hopefully as expected:

```
        column1 column2 column3
0      aba abab   800.0   900.0
1       aaa acc   900.0    60.0
2       bba jka     NaN     NaN
3        fff yy   809.0   400.0
4     hkm asa j     NaN     NaN
5     daa rr oo   521.0   490.0
6   jtuy ww ddw   290.0   321.0
7      bkam ftf    88.0     NaN
8        fgqefc     NaN   600.0
9    daas we fg     NaN     NaN
10   judv mm mk     NaN     NaN
11   hus gg hhh     NaN     NaN
```

But I don't like the use of `df.shift` in `apply`. The problem is that a possible match in the *first row* would lead to a false result without `shift`. Here's a version that avoids this problem and is more straight forward in `apply`:

```
# Preparation
df = pd.concat(
        [pd.DataFrame({col: ['NOT IN LIST' if i == 0 else np.nan]
                       for i, col in enumerate(df.columns)}), df],
        axis='index', 
        ignore_index=True
    )
match = df['column1'].str.fullmatch('|'.join(entry for entry in my_list))
df['shift'] = df.index - match.cumsum()
df.set_index('column1', drop=True, inplace=True)

# Shifting etc.
df = df.apply(lambda row: df.iloc[int(row.at['shift'])], axis='columns')
df[list(match)] = np.nan

# Clean up
df.drop('NOT IN LIST', axis='index', inplace=True)
df.drop('shift', axis='columns', inplace=True)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

(The assumption here is that the string `'NOT IN LIST'` is not in `my_list`. Most likely the empty string `''` would be a good choice too.)

Comment: Thanks for your comments, it's very helpful to me. but, in your first code, i cant operate it, it says "new_values[tuple(axis_indexer)] = fill_value". The problem when i start it on google collab, it say "slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method".

Comment: but, the difference between that link and this question here is i have been completed to achieve column string values to be perfect sentences, not regex. so i think it's enough.

Comment: for more detail of my table, can you check on my real dataframe that i want to perform with your code and what exactly problem occurs, you can check my link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64785356/reshifting-specific-column-based-on-row-if-string-row-match-with-list

Comment: @MRifkyFerdiand I have adjusted the code for both versions and it should work now. The reason for the error is now clear to me. See my answer to your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64785356/reshifting-specific-column-based-on-row-if-string-row-match-with-list/64786800#64786800).

Comment: @MRifkyFerdiand Did it work (works fine with the real frame here)? If you think that my answer was helpful it would be nice if you’d consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Oh god.. thanks for your help to spending so much time for create and evaluate my code. It's work with flows, i have accepted your code bro..

Comment: @MRifkyFerdiand Thanks! I've learned a lot on the way.