# Reshifting specific column based on row if string row match with list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, shift

Okay, it's my real dataframe that i want to perform for reshaping on specific values with list. So
i have this dataframe to reshape.

```
[Out] = df

    Keterangan                                                       Q2 2019        Q2 2018
0   Kas                                                              22686796.0     27421625.0
1   Giro pada bank indonesia                                         68409507.0     71159442.0
2   Giro pada bank lain                                              15675129.0     12584938.0
3   Giro pada bank lain pihak ketiga                                 88548.0        92417.0
4   Giro pada bank lain pihak berelasi                               41391653.0     84668151.0
5   Penempatan pada bank indonesia dan bank lain                     1825890.0      2349900.0
6   Penempatan pada bank indonesia dan bank lain pihak ketiga        28443695.0     30264303.0
7   Penempatan pada bank indonesia dan bank lain pihak berelasi      144798482.0    154020507.0
8   Efek-efek yang diperdagangkan                                    -758.0        -758.0
9   Efek-efek yang diperdagangkan pihak ketiga                       24081797.0     9396553.
10  Efek-efek yang diperdagangkan pihak berelasi                     20253524.0     20584035.0
11  Cadangan kerugian penurunan nilai pada efek-efek                 2713267.0      6858655.0
12  Efek yang dibeli dengan janji dijual kembali                     7014696.0      10165310.0
13  Wesel ekspor dan tagihan lainnya                                 573030.0       1477693.0
14  Wesel ekspor dan tagihan lainnya pihak ketiga                    335008.0       485810.0
15  Wesel ekspor dan tagihan lainnya pihak berelasi                  748120507.0    709223043.0
16  Tagihan akseptasi                                                113999397.0    110787114.0
17  Tagihan akseptasi pihak ketiga                                   -38848157.0    -35017982.0
18  Tagihan akseptasi pihak berelasi                                 NaN            NaN
19  Tagihan derivatif                                                NaN            NaN
20  Tagihan derivatif pihak ketiga                                   NaN            NaN
21  Pinjaman yang diberikan                                          NaN            NaN
22  Pinjaman yang diberikan pihak ketiga                             NaN            NaN
23  Pinjaman yang diberikan pihak berelasi                           NaN            NaN
24  Cadangan kerugian                                                NaN            NaN
```

I want to reshape it with specific list that i have before, here is my list.

```
my_list = ['Giro pada bank lain', 'Penempatan pada bank indonesia dan bank lain', 'Efek-efek yang diperdagangkan', 'Wesel ekspor dan tagihan lainnya', 'Tagihan akseptasi', 'Tagihan derivatif', 'Pinjaman yang diberikan']
```

so, if string contain on column ['Keterangan'] match with item string in list, it will reshape specific column [Q2 2019] and [Q2 2018] to go down. so, here is which dataframe that i want.

```
    [Out] : df1
    Keterangan                                                           Q2 2019        Q2 2018
0   Kas                                                              22686796.0     27421625.0
1   Giro pada bank indonesia                                         68409507.0     71159442.0
2   Giro pada bank lain                                              Nan            Nan
3   Giro pada bank lain pihak ketiga                                 15675129.0     12584938.0
4   Giro pada bank lain pihak berelasi                               88548.0        92417.0
5   Penempatan pada bank indonesia dan bank lain                     Nan            Nan
6   Penempatan pada bank indonesia dan bank lain pihak ketiga        41391653.0     84668151.0
7   Penempatan pada bank indonesia dan bank lain pihak berelasi      1825890.0      2349900.0
8   Efek-efek yang diperdagangkan                                    Nan            Nan
9   Efek-efek yang diperdagangkan pihak ketiga                       28443695.0     30264303.0
10  Efek-efek yang diperdagangkan pihak berelasi                     144798482.0    154020507.0
11  Cadangan kerugian penurunan nilai pada efek-efek                 -758.0        -758.0
12  Efek yang dibeli dengan janji dijual kembali                     24081797.0     9396553
13  Wesel ekspor dan tagihan lainnya                                 Nan            Nan
14  Wesel ekspor dan tagihan lainnya pihak ketiga                    20253524.0     20584035.0
15  Wesel ekspor dan tagihan lainnya pihak berelasi                  2713267.0      6858655.0
16  Tagihan akseptasi                                                Nan            Nan
17  Tagihan akseptasi pihak ketiga                                   7014696.0      10165310.0
18  Tagihan akseptasi pihak berelasi                                 573030.0       1477693.0
19  Tagihan derivatif                                                NaN            NaN
20  Tagihan derivatif pihak ketiga                                   335008.0       485810.0
21  Pinjaman yang diberikan                                          NaN            NaN
22  Pinjaman yang diberikan pihak ketiga                             748120507.0    709223043.0
23  Pinjaman yang diberikan pihak berelasi                           113999397.0    110787114.0
24  Cadangan kerugian                                                -38848157.0    -35017982.0
```

I have to try on some code to reshape it, move df.index to another column and switch column ['Keterangan'] to be index.

```
match = df['Keterangan'].str.fullmatch('|'.join(entry for entry in my_list))
df['shift'] = match.cumsum()
df['index'] = df.index
df.set_index('Keterangan', drop=True, inplace=True)
```

and its work to make shift and swith index.

```
                                                            Q2 2019     Q2 2018   shift index
Keterangan              
Kas                                                         22686796.0  27421625.0  0     0
Giro pada bank indonesia                                    68409507.0  71159442.0  0     1
Giro pada bank lain                                         15675129.0  12584938.0  1     2
Giro pada bank lain pihak ketiga                            88548.0     92417.0     1     3
Giro pada bank lain pihak berelasi                          41391653.0  84668151.0  1     4
Penempatan pada bank indonesia dan bank lain                1825890.0   2349900.0   2     5
Penempatan pada bank indonesia dan bank lain pihak ketiga   28443695.0  30264303.0  2     6
Penempatan pada bank indonesia dan bank lain pihak berelasi 144798482.0 154020507.0 2     7
Efek-efek yang diperdagangkan                               -758.0      -758.0      3     8
Efek-efek yang diperdagangkan pihak ketiga                  24081797.0  9396553.0   3     9
Efek-efek yang diperdagangkan pihak berelasi                20253524.0  20584035.0  3     10
Cadangan kerugian penurunan nilai pada efek-efek yang       2713267.0   6858655.0   3     11
Efek yang dibeli dengan janji dijual kembali                7014696.0   10165310.0  3     12
Wesel ekspor dan tagihan lainnya                            573030.0    1477693.0   4     13
Wesel ekspor dan tagihan lainnya pihak ketiga               335008.0    485810.0    4     14
Wesel ekspor dan tagihan lainnya pihak berelasi             748120507.0 709223043.0 4     15
Tagihan akseptasi                                           113999397.0 110787114.0 5     16
Tagihan akseptasi pihak ketiga                              -38848157.0 -35017982.0 5     17
Tagihan akseptasi pihak berelasi                            NaN         NaN         5     18
Tagihan derivatif                                           NaN         NaN         6     19
Tagihan derivatif pihak ketiga                              NaN         NaN         6     20
Pinjaman yang diberikan                                     NaN         NaN         7     21
Pinjaman yang diberikan pihak ketiga                        NaN         NaN         7     22
Pinjaman yang diberikan pihak berelasi                      NaN         NaN         7     23
Cadangan kerugian                                           NaN         NaN         7     24
```

And next, i want a perform last code for reshifting column,

```
df = df.apply(lambda row: df.shift(row.at['shift']).iloc[row.at['index']], 
axis='columns')
df[list(match)] = np.nan
```

but , it occurs a problem.. it say like this. but, i have been checked a df['index'] type are int64. Why this column cant apply iloc?

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-0f4a937e0002> in <module>()
----> 1 df = df.apply(lambda row: df.shift(row.at['shift']).iloc[row.at['index']], 
axis='columns')
2 df[list(match)] = np.nan
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
1491             key = item_from_zerodim(key)
1492             if not is_integer(key):
-> 1493                 raise TypeError("Cannot index by location index with a non-integer key")
1494 
1495             # validate the location
TypeError: Cannot index by location index with a non-integer key
```

How to resolve the problem and gain df1 that i wish ? anyone can solve it?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see now what's causing the problem. If you look at the result of

```
match = df['Keterangan'].str.fullmatch('|'.join(entry for entry in my_list))
df['shift'] = match.cumsum()
df['index'] = df.index
columns = df.columns
df = df.apply(lambda row: print(row), axis='columns')
```

you will see something like

```
Q2 2019    22686796.0
Q2 2018    27421625.0
shift             0.0
index             0.0
Name: Kas, dtype: float64

Q2 2019    68409507.0
Q2 2018    71159442.0
shift             0.0
index             1.0
Name: Giro pada bank indonesia, dtype: float64

Q2 2019    15675129.0
Q2 2018    12584938.0
shift             1.0
index             2.0
Name: Giro pada bank lain, dtype: float64
...
```

The rows are Series with a unified type, which is `float64` here.

From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

> Objects passed to the function are **Series** objects ...

Some further points. If you look at the simple examples

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [1., 2.]})
print(df.iloc[0], 'w')

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b'], 'B': [1., 2.]})
print(df.iloc[0])
```

you will see the following output

```
A    1.0
B    1.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64

A    a
B    1
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Both are Series. In the first, Pandas sees that all types are numeric, so it chooses the best numeric type to accomodate the types of both values, which is `float`. In the second, due to the string, Pandas chooses `object`, which accomodates almost all types.

In the DataFrame from your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64762456/reshift-nan-values-column-dataframe-if-match-with-list) there's a string in the 2. and 3. column (the `'Nan'`, which isn't `NaN`!), which leads to the type `object` and in the following also to the type `object` in the `row` variables in `apply`. The DataFrame here has tpye `float` in the 2. and 3. column (the type of `NaN` is `float`) and therefore also `float` in the `row` variables. That's the reason why the original code worked for the first example but not here. (At least that's what I think, I could be wrong.)

I have adjusted the code in my [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64762456/reshift-nan-values-column-dataframe-if-match-with-list/64771127#64771127) accordingly (`int` casts).